# I cant enter decrypt key to get into ubuntu, the characters are typing in upper left corner of screen instead of decript box in center

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, password, luks, decryption

I have a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 Installation. This was a tricky setup to get an Encrypted Ubuntu install as Dual Boot with Win10 Pro.

I mostly followed the recommendations as per [this article](https://www.hecticgeek.com/how-to-setup-encrypted-ubuntu-installation/) (except did no disk shrinking, skipped the windows instructions). The Windows setup (done first) was standard. No encryption (for gaming). I gave its partition most of the HDD and boots and is working fine.

Now, during the Ubuntu setup, I manually added a 500Mb unencrypted Ext4 boot partition and a 200Gb Root partition in Luks+Ext4. The install wizard did the rest but, after rebooting, I cannot enter the decryption code in the entry field. The text I'm typing is appearing in the upper left hand corner of the screen and easily readable.

I have basic Linux skills and have never encountered this issue with my other encrypted machines (not dual boot). Goggle found one instance similar with no solution, just a work around idea that kind of works (with many hoops) but for a version 5 revisions older than this Ubuntu (16.04) so there must be a solution out there by now.

| Hardware | Details |
| --- | --- |
| System: | Dell 9020 Optiplex |
| CPU: | Core i7 4th Gen |
| Storage: | WD Blue 1Tb SSD |
| Video: | EVGA RTX 2060 Super |
| Other: | StarTech 4 port USB 3.0 Card |
| Monitors: | (1) Acer X34 (Display Port) (2) 720p (HDMI) ⇠ not in use right now |

I've attached a horrible picture of the screen in question. The text in the upper left is where the keyboard is actually typing it's text instead of the box in the center (under "Ubuntu").

**Other Hardware Issues:**

- numlock won't work
- mouse doesn't work
- <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not appear to be working

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Could you update your question to share a bit more info and perhaps a photo of the wrongly-placed text? What sort of hardware are you running? This could provide some additional context to help solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, good suggestion. Done. Don't know how to screen capture here so took picture. Please don't kill your eyes trying to read it. It says "Hello, this is NOT where I wish to type my paraphrase right now". Thanks

Comment: Given the number of hardware issues you're reporting, I would go out on a limb and say that something within the install is messed up. Your video card will need at least 18.04 in order for you to get the most out of it and the issue in the picture looks like something that `gdm3` used to do a while back when the older, proprietary nVidia drivers were installed. Would it be possible to use a newer release of Ubuntu?

Comment: I could try again with a new version. I believe I didn't express myself properly. Those are not hardware issues. Tab works fine, it just doesn't work in a windows like manner where it will jump you from one section to another. It just tabs x characters across in that line where the text is appearing. Ubuntu has no mouse function at all during this paraphrase entry screen. This is normal. I just wish it had so I could solve this problem.

Comment: The lack of numlock control however might be unusual but I cant be sure. My other PCs are laptops with no numlock lamp so I don't know if it's normal that it isn't working here or not. It functions normally the rest of the time. Can someone please confirm numlock is non-functional when at this screen? Thanks, much appreciated.

Comment: Tried Ubuntu 18.04 and it does work to enter the paraphrase for the disk encryption, but this Gnome version of Ubuntu is a completely different OS. After loosing a massive amount of time trying to get this version to work for me with little success, I'm dumping it and going back to ver 16.04. Don't have time to master yet another new OS again, I'll suffer through the hoops instead if I have to. Might change my username. Not very happy anymore. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the current updated drivers now (Jan 2021) have fixed this problem. It looks like it may have been the GeForce Video driver at the time that I used with Ubuntu 16.04 so using the very latest driver from Nvidia did the trick. Typing the Passcode to decrypt the Hard Drive now enters the text in the proper box instead of the upper left hand corner of the display.

Note: Version 18.04 of Ubuntu that uses the X-org video drivers I believe also does not have this problem. Logging into encrypted drive works normally as well.

Problem solved.

Comment: Problem maybe not so solved. I ran into other problems so I re-installed Ubuntu 16.04.06 with version 460.32.03 Nvidia Drivers for the RTX card and the problem returned. I also learned by using a displayport source switch that I CAN enter decrypt paraphrase when running from the built in Intel display port, but not the RTX card port. (Not sure where monitor was plugged into when I got solution above.)

Comment: More info discovered. After installing the Nvidia Drivers, I now finally have a X.Org server driver available in "Additional Drivers" to select from (including a few previous Nvidia drivers versions). I tested this problem above using the X.Org and, well, it works for monitors plugged into the built in Intel port. The monitors connected to the RTX card are not available. It appears that this driver does not see the RTX card at all.